# error when trying to download Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15,1

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to download Visual Studio 2017 15.1 Enterprise multiple languages. I do not get a download link to an `iso` file as in previous versions.

Instead, I get mu_visual_studio_enterprise_2017_version_15_1_x86_x64_10254674_exe?t=eea598d1-f667-477e-939f-ccc821490c4b&e=1491849265&h=1049f47ec6f5424fc0282e03d34eb8b0

I can neither open it or download it even stripping out what is after the question mark.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be valid download link.. are you sure you din't miss anything in your MSDN downloads? Or are you trying to download from somewhere else?

Comment: There aren't  `.iso` of Visual Studio 2017: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17541385-please-make-iso-files-for-visual-studio-2017